# syntax of javascript in creating circle

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm new of javascript language and I'm trying to create a circle using `setOptions` method and writing this code, but unfortunately it didn't work.there is some mistake in my code?

```
circle_0.setOptions({
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapCentre.lat(), mapCentre.lng()),
    radius: 2000
});
```

Comment: Check your browser's developer's console for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks ok. Maybe this contain wrong values? mapCentre.lat(), mapCentre.lng()